# IMAP query to get messages with `INTERNALDATE` higher than given datetime

Tags: python, imap

How do I write an IMAP query to get all messages with `INTERNALDATE` higher than a given datetime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666463/imap-search-criteria-imaplib-python). However for further clarification you can read the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501).

Comment: For those of us who would rather not peruse the 216-page-long IMAP RFC, can someone please weigh in and say whether there's any possibility of filtering messages by datetime rather than just date?

Comment: 216-page-long IMAP RFC is probably too much, but 84 characters comment should be easy enough to read. The answer is in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

SEARCH SINCE. Only works at day resolution though.